# Setting delegate to another object in Cocoaasyncsocket

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I was trying to write a simple UDP client that can send and receive data and I want to set the delegate to another object other than self.

I am able to send data but not able to receive any back from the server. The server is working fine.

My code is as below:

```
//ViewController.m
- (void)setupSocket
{

    UDPReveiver * udp = [[UDPReveiver alloc] init];
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:udp delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![udpSocket bindToPort:5528 error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error binding: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error receiving: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Socket Created :)");
}

//UDPReceiver.h

@interface UDPReveiver : NSObject <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>

//UDPReceiver.m

- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
  fromAddress:(NSData *)address
withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Hey");
    if (msg)
    {
        NSLog(@"Data received is :%@",msg);
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `UDPReveiver *udp` will be released when it goes out scope, which is right away.  Some object, for example maybe the view controller that's creating the `udp`, needs to be that delegate's owner, keeping it in a `strong` property.  That gives the udp instance a retain count above zero, thereby keeping around.  So ...

```
// in the ViewController's interface...
@property(strong, nonatomic) UDPReveiver *udp;
```

Then your setup...

```
- (void)setupSocket
{
    self.udp = [[UDPReveiver alloc] init];
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self.udp delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    // and so on
```

When you're done with the socket, your view controller can discard the delegate, like this:

```
self.udp = nil;
```

... or it will be released when the view controller is released.